# Proving Basis of a type (1,1) Tensor

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, tensor-products, tensors, multilinear-algebra

I am trying to teach myself tensor products, and I often see claims that the basis for a type (p,q) tensor is of the form: $e_{i_1}\otimes \ldots e_{i_q}\otimes e^{j_1}\otimes \ldots \otimes e^{j_p}$. I have never seen explicit proofs that this is a basis by showing linear independence, so I am trying to do this on my own in a simple and explicit case for a tensor of type (1,1).

I am assuming my vector space V is 2 dimensional with basis $e_1,e_2$, and $V^*$ with basis $e^1, e^2$, such that $e^i(e_j) = \delta ^i_j$. Then for a (1,1) tensor I wish to show the linear independence of:

$$ T_{11} (e_1\otimes e^1) + T_{12} (e_1\otimes e^2) + T_{21} (e_2\otimes e^1)  + T_{22} (e_2\otimes e^2)  = 0$$

But I am unsure how to show this to be the case.

Comment: Show that their action on vectors is linearly independent. This amounts to showing that the space of $2 \times 2$ matrices has a basis given by the matrices with a $1$ in each entry and $0$ otherwise. Alternatively you can try to prove the more general statement that if $\{ e_i \}$ is a basis of $V$ and $\{ f_j \}$ is a basis of $W$, then $\{ e_i \otimes f_j \}$ is a basis of $V \otimes W$, then use this repeatedly (for the general case).

Comment: $e_i \otimes e_j$ is not the basis of a tensor ; instead a matrix $M$ can be written as an expansion $M = M^{ij}  e_i \otimes e_j$; $e_i \otimes e_j$ is the basis of  any  $M \in V \otimes V$ where $V$ is a vector space with basis $\{e_i\}$.   You can prove independence by noting that for $A^{ij} e_i \otimes e_j=0$ we must have $B^j \otimes e_j =0$ where $B^j=A^{ij} e_i$. Since $e_j$ are independent this is only possible if $B^j=0$  which is only the case if $A^{ij}=0$ since $e_i$ are independent.